# Different behaviour of fread() on online editor and the local machine (C++)

Tags: c++, c, stdin, fread

When I use `fread()` in a C++ code and compile it (using gcc) on online editors, it works fine. But when I run the same code on my local machine, it waits infinitely unless I hit ctrl+z on my windows PC. Why is it so?

I'm reading from stdin in the code (in case this helps).

Here is the code (its not mine, though. I'm just using it to understand it).

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
#define size 65536
int main()
{

char b[size];
int t=0,n,k,cnt=0;
int c,j;
scanf("%d %d\n",&n,&k);
printf("%d %d\n", n, k);
while((c = fread(b,1,size,stdin))>0)
{
     printf("%d\n",c);
           for(j=0;j<c;j++)
           {
            if(b[j]=='\n')
            {
                          if(t%k==0)cnt++;
                          t = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                          t = (t*10) + (b[j]-'0');                
            }              
           }
 }
printf("%d\n",cnt);    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `fread` and asking it for (up to) 65536 bytes. There aren't that many bytes on stdin, and so the call hangs until stdin is closed. It's closed right away in the online editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It reads until it reaches the end of the input stream.

The online editor pipes the input stream from a file (or similar), and it ends at the end of the provided input.

Your local machine reads it from the console (unless you pipe something into the program instead), and it doesn't end until you use Ctrl-Z to close the input stream.

Comment: Oh, so @MikeSeymour you mean that the online editor's file has an EOF at the end - something that is missing when I run it on my local machine?

Comment: @abhishek_naik: Yes. If you pipe the input from somewhere (as online editors typically do), then the input stream will end at the end of that input. From the console, it won't end until you tell it to.

Comment: @abhishek_naik the file doesn't actually contain "EOF"  - but when you pipe a file into your program, the operating system signals the EOF condition when you have read all of the file and you try to read more.  However at a console there is no way of knowing whether or not you intend to type more things in, other than having you specifically indicate that you are done.